# RadGrid Batch edit mode - read only column missing in OnBatchEditCommand

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm using RadGrid in batch edit mode.  I have one column (line number) which is read-only.  When I call `grid.get_batchEditingManager().saveAllChanges()`, I only get the values from the non-read-only columns.  I need the line number in order to update my data table correctly but I do not want the line number column to be editable.  What is the correct approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save line number in [DataKeyNames](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-retrieve-primary-key-field-values-for-items.html).

For example,

```
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="LineNumber" ...>
```